# Formatting a Log file in PowerShell or Batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a log file that looks that looks like the example below:

```
[hh:mm:ss] LINE 1 GOES HERE
   LINE 2 GOES HERE
   LINE 3 GOES HERE
   LINE 4 GOES HERE
[hh:mm:ss] LINE 5 IS HERE
```

I'm looking for a way to format this file somewhat like this

```
[hh:mm:ss] LINE 1 GOES HERE LINE 2 GOES HERE LINE 3 GOES HERE LINE 4 GOES HERE
[hh:mm:ss] LINE 5 GOES HERE
```

Is there any easy way to do this in `PowerShell` or `CMD.exe` ? Any help is appreciated!

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
$path = "---path to file----"
Get-Content "$path" | Where { $_.trim() -ne ""} | Set-Content "$path"
```

This only moves lines up if there is an empty line above, but doesn't really move empty lines behind the original line.

Comment: using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - `jrepl "^(\[\d\d:\d\d:\d\d])?.*" "$txt=false;output.write(($1?ln-1?'\r\n':'':' ')+$0)" /jmatchq /f "test.txt" /o -`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Updated based on your example code.

I pasted your example into log.log and did this in Powershell:

```
((Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot/log.log") -join "`n").Replace("`n"," ").Replace("[","`n[") | Set-Content "$PSScriptRoot/log.log"
```